# unexpected identifier error in grunt.js file

Tags: gruntjs

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the following error in terminal when running the following  grunt.js file?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    concat: { // Here is where we do our concatenating
      dist: {
      src: [
      'components/js/*.js' // everything in the src js folder
    ],
    dest: 'js/script.js',
    }
    }

    uglify: {
    build: {
    src: 'js/script.js',
    dest: 'js/script.min.js'
    }
    }

});

//Add all the plugins here
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

//What happens when we type 'grunt' in the terminal
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

The error I get is:

```
Loading "gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
```

> > SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> >     Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

THANKS!

Comment: This question is *way* too specific. I have the exact same error message but a completely different gruntfile.js (which is also much larger). The current accepted answer is specific to the problem and is not very useful for solving similar problems. A much better question is "How can I find what is causing Syntax errors in gruntfile.js?" which, when answered, is useful to many more people.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### You have a missing comma:

```js
grunt.initConfig({

  pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: [
        'components/js/*.js'
      ],
      dest: 'js/script.js',
    }
  }, // <---- here was a missing comma

  uglify: {
    build: {
      src: 'js/script.js',
      dest: 'js/script.min.js'
    }
  }
});
```

#### Make yourself a favor and use coffeescript!

```
module.exports = (grunt) ->
  grunt.initConfig

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json")

    concat:
      dist:
        src: ["components/js/*.js"]
        dest: "js/script.js"

    uglify:
      build:
        src: "js/script.js"
        dest: "js/script.min.js"


  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-concat"
  grunt.loadNpmTasks "grunt-contrib-uglify"

  grunt.registerTask "default", [
    "concat"
    "uglify"
  ]
```

Comment: Despite having everything else correct I also stumbled over the missing comma, thank you for pointing this out, it was even in the same spot.